# How to improve simple macros to leave the surrounding text justification undisturbed

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

I have prepared a series of macros in order to simplify the incorporation of pictures into long documents. All of them are based onthe MWE below.  However I have just noticed that the text following the pictures is no longer justified properly on the right margin. What is the good way to correct this? Obviously I would like the macros calling pictures to be neutral regarding the surrounding text.

```
\documentclass [draft]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx} 
\newcommand{\ThreePicturesThreeCaptions}[7]{%
%Usage[7 arguments]{file1}{caption1}{file2}{caption2}{file3}{caption3}{global-caption}
\centering
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth] {#1}\caption {#2}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\textwidth}%
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{#3}\caption {#4}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{#5}\caption {#6}
\end{minipage}
\caption{#7}
\end{figure}
\raggedright
}%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\ThreePicturesThreeCaptions {144415-0009.jpg}{contacts \#22}{144615-0012.jpg}{contacts  \#16}{143207-0005.jpg}{\label{Quadrax}quadrax}{\label{ThreePictures}Typical picture layout generated for a laboratory report}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the first `\centering` at the beginning and the `\raggedright` at the end of your macro.

Comment: It works... Can you please convert your suggestion into an answer, so I can close my question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your definition of `\ThreePicturesThreeCaptions` sets `\centering` *before* the `{figure}` environment and also (more important here) `\raggedright` *after* the `{figure}` environment. Both are not wanted. The effect of the `\centering` is cancelled by `\raggedright`, anyway, and `\raggedright` switches to -- well -- ragged right text. If you remove both everything should be fine.

```
\newcommand{\ThreePicturesThreeCaptions}[7]{%
  \centering % <= unwanted
  \begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
   ...
  \end{figure}
  \raggedright % <= unwanted
}
```